# Pushing an application revision using the SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

To push a revision using CLI, there is a [command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/push.html) like :

```
aws deploy push --application-name WordPress_App --description 
"This is my deployment" --ignore-hidden-files --s3-location 
s3://CodeDeployDemoBucket/WordPressApp.zip --source
/tmp/MyLocalDeploymentFolder/
```

How could I do this using the [SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeDeploy.html)? I couldn't find a method, that will help me push the application to S3 storage, although there is a method to create a deployment `(createDeployment)`

Answer (score 1):

The push command in the CLI is a CodeDeploy plugin for AWS CLI, you can find the source code here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/customizations/codedeploy/push.py

It's actually calling several different APIs to create the revision bundle, upload it and create a deployment. With SDK, you can achieve the same thing by creating your own wrapper which will call APIs following the same order.